# Why does Prettier claim the `;` before destructuring assignment?

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I have `if` block in my **Angular** component:

```
if (desc.length > 0) {
    [this.errorMsg] = desc
}
```

However, **Prettier** doesn't like it and recommends to put `;` at the beginning of the destructuring assignment:

```
if (desc.length > 0) {
    ;[this.errorMsg] = desc
}
```

I just want to get **why**? Is there a bug in my **ESLint** or **Prettier** configuration? Or does it have reasons?

**ADDED**
**.eslintrc.json:**

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.*?.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        // AirBnB guide style
        "airbnb-typescript/base",
        // Prettier settings
        "prettier",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        /**
         * Any TypeScript source code (NOT TEMPLATE) related rules you wish to use/reconfigure over and above the
         * recommended set provided by the @angular-eslint project would go here.
         */
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          { "type": "attribute", "prefix": "app", "style": "camelCase" }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          { "type": "element", "prefix": "app", "style": "kebab-case" }
        ]
      }
    },
    // NOTE: WE ARE NOT APPLYING PRETTIER IN THIS OVERRIDE, ONLY @ANGULAR-ESLINT/TEMPLATE
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    // NOTE: WE ARE NOT APPLYING @ANGULAR-ESLINT/TEMPLATE IN THIS OVERRIDE, ONLY PRETTIER
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "excludedFiles": ["*inline-template-*.component.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        // NOTE: WE ARE OVERRIDING THE DEFAULT CONFIG TO ALWAYS SET THE PARSER TO ANGULAR (SEE BELOW)
        "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "parser": "angular" }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**.prettierrc.json:**

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "semi": false
}
```

Comment: ESLint's warning message doesn't offer any clues?

Comment: @meriton, I've gotten it's a message of **Prettier**, not **ESLint**. I gonna update my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already got a [bunch of discussion](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1935#issuecomment-306729468) about this subject, if your interested to read the why

> The reason why the prettier add semi-colon at the start, even if it isn't strictly required, is that it makes it easier to move lines of code around the file without accidentally introducing ASI issues. - [azz](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1935#issuecomment-305968919)

*Edit:* Prettier does also explain the reason why [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#semicolons)

But basically, it's because

```js
someCall()
[a] = obj
```

isn't the same as

```js
someCall();
[a] = obj
```

but since you ask prettier to remove the semi-colon, then it put it at the beggining

```js
someCall()
;[a] = obj
```

You can also read the [standardjs rules about the subject](https://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons) which says

```js
// ✓ ok
;[1, 2, 3].forEach(bar)

// ✗ avoid
[1, 2, 3].forEach(bar)
```

Comment: I couldn't find it in Google, thx for yo answer!

Comment: This is also documented in Prettier's docs: https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#semicolons

Comment: Thx @thorn̈ I did add this information to the response